# Get data on API yelp

Tags: php, api, yelp

I have to use the Yelp API in php to create a small box with reviews from yelp for my company,
I never use it, and I read the doc this morning.
I understand how t works, but I don't understand how to get the data from the response
{'businesses': 
[{'address1': '466 Haight St', 
'address2': '', 
'address3': '', etc...... 
}}
My url is simple, I just enter the name of the business like: 
$url="http://api.yelp.com/business_review_searchterm=$term&location=$city%2A%20CA&ywsid=$key"; with all the var ok.

Can you help me please, I just want to know how to get this data
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use PHP's `json_decode` function to turn this into a PHP object.

```
$response = json_decode("{'businesses': [{'address1': '466 Haight St', 'address2': '', 'address3': '', etc...... }}");

// to view structure
print_r($response);

// access the first business address1
print $response->businesses[0]->address1;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do to get "businesses etc" from my url? I can't do json_decode($url), My question is to be able to treat this url, I don't know if I explain well :/ –

Comment: Ok, I use file_get_contents to exract, and after I use json_decode, and it seems to work, thanks. Now, I have to get the stars and the first review, if you have any idea

Comment: You should be able to figure that out based off the print_r.